# I am running into an issue using ImportJSON w/ Google Sheets to import data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to set up a database of all player items with overalls and series. I can pull the top level (items) but anything below that I get an "Error Getting Data".

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BbIrzYJEqEw_eOqgKXBueDhTUKGLIlMaQVbwEIT5f9Q/edit?usp=sharing

I tried using [bradjasper's](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs) ImportJSON script but kept getting:

Exception: Attribute provided with no value: url

ImportJSONAdvanced  @ importJSON.gs:217

`var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);`

ImportJSON  @ importJSON.gs:68

`return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, null, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);`

The one I am currently using is below and I was able to pull "items" but "items/name" or anything else fails to retrieve data. I am new to this and have been dredging around the web trying to find a solution without success. You guys have been extremely helpful in the past, any insight would be much appreciated.

````
* Imports JSON data to your spreadsheet Ex: IMPORTJSON("http://myapisite.com","city/population")
* @param url URL of your JSON data as string
* @param xpath simplified xpath as string
* @customfunction
*/
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){
  
  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    
    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);
    
    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }
    
    //Logger.log(typeof(json));
    
    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];
      
      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }
  
} ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
var resTable = []; 
function getDataJSON(url,xpath){
  var data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())
  var json = eval('data.items')
  if (typeof xpath == 'object'){var liste = xpath.join().split(",")} else {var liste = xpath.split("|")}
  if (json.length){json.forEach(function(elem){getData(elem,liste)})} else {getData(json,liste)}
  return resTable
}
function getData(elem,liste){
  var prov=[]
  liste.forEach(function(chemin){
    var t=chemin.split('/');
    var obj=elem;
    for (var i=1;i<t.length;i++){obj=obj.item(t[i])}
    if(typeof obj=='object'){prov.push('['+obj+']')}else{prov.push(obj)}
  })
  resTable.push(prov)
}
Object.prototype.item=function(i){return this[i]};
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oy00ZZJCDYlzyCfdeIchvOUaCttbzuUeCKkacDuHeuk/copy

Comment: You're incredible. Could I add something to that to grab all data from all pages? If not I can work around it by using "&page" every 25 rows.

Comment: how many pages are there ? can we know the number of pages before launching the script or do we have to try until we get an error ?

Comment: I apologize for not including that, 97 pages.

Comment: Sorry, but it exceed maximum execution time. Until 20 pages, it seems correct. take a new copy ... (number of pages is in A1)